# How to loop object have many array object like that

Tags: javascript

I have object 1 like that

```
const object1 = {
  Sheet1: [
    { A: '', B: '', C: '', D: '', E: '' },
    {
      A: 'Cash Report - Processed',
      B: 'Store: 54101   Date: 1/30/2020',
      D: '',
      E: ''
    },
    { A: '', B: '', C: '', D: 'Adj: 00', E: 'Adj: 01' },
  ],
  Sheet2: [ { D: 'a' }, { G: 's' }, { G: 'b' } ]
};
```

I want delete blank data but I have issue when I loop object 1, I can't get keym my code

```
Object.keys(object1).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key, object1[key]);
});
```

I want data will like that

```
 {
  Sheet1: [
    {
      A: 'Cash Report - Processed',
      B: 'Store: 54101   Date: 1/30/2020',

    },
    { D: 'Adj: 00', E: 'Adj: 01' },
  ],
  Sheet2: [ { D: 'a' }, { G: 's' }, { G: 'b' } ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using `Object.entries` and `Array.reduce`.

```js
const input = {
  Sheet1: [
    { A: '', B: '', C: '', D: '', E: '' },
    {
      A: 'Cash Report - Processed',
      B: 'Store: 54101   Date: 1/30/2020',
      D: '',
      E: ''
    },
    { A: '', B: '', C: '', D: 'Adj: 00', E: 'Adj: 01' },
  ],
  Sheet2: [ { D: 'a' }, { G: 's' }, { G: 'b' } ]
};

const output = Object.entries(input).reduce((acc, cur) => {
  acc[cur[0]] = cur[1].reduce((curAcc, curVal) => {
    const notNull = Object.entries(curVal).filter(([ key, val ]) => val);
    if (notNull.length > 0) {
      curAcc.push(Object.fromEntries(notNull));
    }
    return curAcc;
  }, []);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for(const key in object1){
  const element = object1[key];
  object1[key] = element.map(x => {
    for(const prop in x){
      if(!x[prop]){
        delete x[prop];
      }
    }
    
    return Object.keys(x).length ? x : null
  }).filter(x => !!x);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Object.entries` to transform object to array of key-value pairs, manipulate that pairs, remove pairs with empty value, then transform back to object using `Object.fromEntries`

```js
const object1 = {
  Sheet1: [
    { A: "", B: "", C: "", D: "", E: "" },
    {
      A: "Cash Report - Processed",
      B: "Store: 54101   Date: 1/30/2020",
      D: "",
      E: "",
    },
    { A: "", B: "", C: "", D: "Adj: 00", E: "Adj: 01" },
  ],
  Sheet2: [{ D: "a" }, { G: "s" }, { G: "b" }],
}

const notEmptyObject = (obj) => Object.keys(obj).length > 0

const removeEmptyValues = (obj) =>
  Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([_, value]) => Boolean(value)))

const res = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(object1).map(([sheet, data]) => [
    sheet,
    data
      .map(removeEmptyValues)
      .filter(notEmptyObject),
  ])
)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: I can't think transform object to array .. I just focus object so I can't find solution, tks so much I't nice